# How to add a text box on submit in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new to angular and from documentation on official site and using plunkr I was able to figure out we use ng-repeat and push method to add something new to DOM if I am not wrong.

I am trying to go through this example found on docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example - example-ngController-production</title>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
        <script>
            angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
                .controller('SettingsController1', SettingsController1);

            function SettingsController1() {
                this.name = "John Smith";
                this.contacts = [
                    {type: 'phone', value: '408 555 1212'},
                    {type: 'email', value: 'john.smith@example.org'}
                ];
            }

            SettingsController1.prototype.greet = function () {
                alert(this.name);
            };
            SettingsController1.prototype.addContact = function () {
                this.contacts.push({ value: ''});
            };
            SettingsController1.prototype.removeContact = function (contactToRemove) {
                var index = this.contacts.indexOf(contactToRemove);
                this.contacts.splice(index, 1);
            };
            SettingsController1.prototype.clearContact = function (contact) {
                contact.type = 'phone';
                contact.value = '';
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="controllerAsExample">
        <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings">
            <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="settings.name"/></label>
            <button ng-click="settings.greet()">greet</button><br/>
            Contact:
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="contact in settings.contacts">
                    <select ng-model="contact.type" aria-label="Contact method" id="select_{{$index}}">
                        <option>phone</option>
                        <option>email</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.value" aria-labelledby="select_{{$index}}" />
                    <button ng-click="settings.clearContact(contact)">clear</button>
                    <button ng-click="settings.removeContact(contact)" aria-label="Remove">X</button>
                </li>
                <li><button ng-click="settings.addContact()">add</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is kind basic overview I understood, but I am not able to figure out how ng-repeat is helping us to add a new element(push a new element). As far as I can see its acting like a iterator in java.

Comment: What is your actual question here? Are you asking for an explanation of how `ng-repeat` works?

Comment: Basically I want to understand how to create/add textbox on submit

Comment: you aren't trying to add a new `textbox` in this code.  you are adding a new element to the `contacts` array, which ng-repeat is in turn generating an `<li>` for, which happens to have a `select` and a `textbox` in it.

Comment: if you are asking, in general terms, why this actually works, then you probably should study a bit more about how 2 way bindings work in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

To do it the Angular way, you could have an array of text field meta values, e.g.

```
formFieldArr = [{fieldName: 'name', minLength: '2' ... } , {fieldName: 'gender', minLength: '4' ... }]
```

Have an ng-repeat to loop over and render the text fields.

In HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="formFieldArr">
    <input name="formField.name" ng-minlength="formField.minLength">
</div>
```

In your submit codes, all you need is to add to the array and the form fields will be rendered.

```
FormFieldPost.save(){
    onsuccess:
        formFieldArr.push("{fieldName: 'gender', minLength: '4' ... }");
}
```

If you are thinking in terms of DOM, that will be more of a jQuery solution.

---

Expanding further, you could also use the same array to render different kinds of form fields.

```
formFieldArr = [{fieldName: 'name', minLength: '2', fieldType: 'select' ... } , {fieldName: 'gender', minLength: '4', fieldTypre: 'text' ... }]
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="formFieldArr">
    <input name="formField.name" ng-minlength="formField.minLength" ng-show="formField.fieldType === 'text'">
... Do similar ng-show for select.
</div>
```

(Typing on mobile)

Comment: Thank you. So we first bind to formFieldArr and then push new values into it right?

Comment: Yup I will do that. And you could expand it to be able to render any kinds of Input Fields like { ... fieldType="select"} ... In your HTML, use ng-show/if to display accordingly.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's wrong with this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/GpeAqjP7fl78qEx634Ur?p=preview

Comment: @kittu there are multiple issues with the plunker you posted in the comments here; it might be best if you pose that as a new question.  chief among the issues are that you are using `ng-submit` which is for form submission, but you don't actually have a form; try `ng-click` instead.

Comment: @kittu also check the console, you have syntax errors which you should correct before asking for assistance on a code snippet.

Comment: @Claies  already fixed my problem long back.Thanks for letting me know about the console. I will check it from on ;)